# creating json array from php array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've following array in php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [team1_score] => 10
            [team2_score] => 5
            [round_number] => 1
            [teamtitle1] => Chennai super kings
            [teamtitle2] => Spartans
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [team1_score] => 15
            [team2_score] => 10
            [round_number] => 1
            [teamtitle1] => Lions11
            [teamtitle2] => Kings Xl Punjab
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [team1_score] => 15
            [team2_score] => 5
            [round_number] => 1
            [teamtitle1] => Zimbabwe
            [teamtitle2] => Red Steel
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [team1_score] => 10
            [team2_score] => 15
            [round_number] => 2
            [teamtitle1] => Zimbabwe
            [teamtitle2] => Chennai super kings
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [team1_score] => 
            [team2_score] => 
            [round_number] => 3
            [teamtitle1] => 
            [teamtitle2] => 
        )
)
```

I want to generate tournament brackets from this array. I'd found jquery plugin for creating tournament brackets. For generating the tournament brackets I've to form json array round wise. for round 1 it should give me 3 records for round 2 1 records and for round 3 1 record. I've tried the following code :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            (function (win, doc, $) {
                win.TestData<?php echo $cnt; ?> = [
<?php
foreach ($roundmatcharr as $mt => $matchval) {
    if (isset($matchval["teamtitle1"]) && $matchval["teamtitle1"] != "") {
        $team1 = $matchval["teamtitle1"];
    } else {
        $team1 = "Team 1";
    }

    if (isset($matchval["teamtitle2"]) && $matchval["teamtitle2"] != "") {
        $team2 = $matchval["teamtitle2"];
    } else {
        $team2 = "Team 2";
    }

    if (isset($matchval["team1_score"]) && $matchval["team1_score"] != "") {
        $team1score = $matchval["team1_score"];
    } else {
        $team1score = 0;
        ;
    }

    if (isset($matchval["team2_score"]) && $matchval["team2_score"] != "") {
        $team2score = $matchval["team2_score"];
    } else {
        $team2score = 0;
        ;
    }
    ?>
                        [
                                [{"name": "<?php echo $team1; ?>", "id": "<?php echo $team1; ?>", "seed": 1, "score": "<?php echo $team1score; ?>"}, {"name": "<?php echo $team2; ?>", "id": "<?php echo $team2; ?>", "seed": 2, "score": "<?php echo $team2score; ?>"}],
                        ],
<?php } ?>
                ];
                $(".my_gracket").gracket({src: win.TestData<?php echo $cnt; ?>});
            })(window, document, jQuery);
</script>
```

It is giving me output like this:-

```
win.TestData = [
[
[ {"name" : "Chennai super kings", "id" : "Chennai super kings", "seed" : 1, "score" : "10" }, {"name" : "Spartans", "id" : "Spartans", "seed" : 2, "score" : "5"} ],
], 
[
[ {"name" : "Lions11", "id" : "Lions11", "seed" : 1, "score" : "15" }, {"name" : "Kings Xl Punjab", "id" : "Kings Xl Punjab", "seed" : 2, "score" : "10"} ],
], 
[
[ {"name" : "Zimbabwe", "id" : "Zimbabwe", "seed" : 1, "score" : "15" }, {"name" : "Red Steel", "id" : "Red Steel", "seed" : 2, "score" : "5"} ],
], 
[
[ {"name" : "Zimbabwe", "id" : "Zimbabwe", "seed" : 1, "score" : "10" }, {"name" : "Chennai super kings", "id" : "Chennai super kings", "seed" : 2, "score" : "15"} ],
], 
[
[ {"name" : "Team 1", "id" : "Team 1", "seed" : 1, "score" : "0" }, {"name" : "Team 2", "id" : "Team 2", "seed" : 2, "score" : "0"} ],
], 
];
which is not correct. The output should be like this:-

win.TestData = [
[
[ {"name" : "Chennai super kings", "id" : "Chennai super kings", "seed" : 1, "score" : "10" }, {"name" : "Spartans", "id" : "Spartans", "seed" : 2, "score" : "5"} ],
[ {"name" : "Lions11", "id" : "Lions11", "seed" : 1, "score" : "15" }, {"name" : "Kings Xl Punjab", "id" : "Kings Xl Punjab", "seed" : 2, "score" : "10"} ],
[ {"name" : "Zimbabwe", "id" : "Zimbabwe", "seed" : 1, "score" : "15" }, {"name" : "Red Steel", "id" : "Red Steel", "seed" : 2, "score" : "5"} ],
], 
[
[ {"name" : "Zimbabwe", "id" : "Zimbabwe", "seed" : 1, "score" : "10" }, {"name" : "Chennai super kings", "id" : "Chennai super kings", "seed" : 2, "score" : "15"} ],
], 
[
[ {"name" : "Team 1", "id" : "Team 1", "seed" : 1, "score" : "0" }, {"name" : "Team 2", "id" : "Team 2", "seed" : 2, "score" : "0"} ],
], 
];
```

Round 1 matches should be in first array then second and the so on.

Comment: And whats the issue over here

Comment: the json array is not coming round wise. it is coming as same for all the records

Comment: What do you mean by roundwise

Comment: there is a field in array as round_number. for round_number 1 there are three matches so the new array should start after 3 matches but it is starting from second match itself

Comment: @Uchiha Please reply me what should be the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is if you first build the data into the right structure in PHP, which makes it easier to manipulate. Then you can output it as JSON using `json_encode`.

```
<?php
$rounds = [];
$output = [];

// Format data and sort by round
foreach ($roundmatcharr as $matchval) {

    $match1 = new stdClass();
    $match1->name = $matchval['teamtitle1'];
    $match1->id = $matchval['teamtitle1'];
    $match1->seed = 1;
    $match1->score = $matchval['team1_score'];

    $match2 = new stdClass();
    $match2->name = $matchval['teamtitle2'];
    $match2->id = $matchval['teamtitle2'];
    $match2->seed = 2;
    $match2->score = $matchval['team2_score'];

    $rounds[$matchval['round_number']][] = [$match1, $match2];

}

// Extra loop to clean up round numbers
foreach ($rounds as $round) {
    $output[] = $round;
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (win, doc, $) {
        win.TestData<?php echo $cnt; ?> = <?php echo json_encode($output); ?>;
        $(".my_gracket").gracket({src: win.TestData<?php echo $cnt; ?>});
    })(window, document, jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response it helps me a lot dude. Thanks very much for your time. I really Appreciate it. One problem i've to show this when team name and score is null so at that time how to build the array?

Comment: If those are null then they'll appear in the final output as null as well. How you handle that depends on your brackets script - leave them as is, skip them or replace the nulls with another value like "unknown"